# inline function in visual c++ 6.0

Tags: c++, makefile

I have some static bool inline function in the project (it's not my code):

```
static bool inline
is_safe_raw(CHAR_DATA *ch, CHAR_DATA *victim)
{
    /*
     * ghosts are safe
     * this check must be done first to avoid
     * suicyco who recite 'leather-bound book' (#5743)
     * without any target specified
     * extracted NPCs are safe too
     */
    if (!IS_NPC(victim)) {
        int clan;

        /* ghost cannot attack anyone */
        if (ch != victim
        &&  !IS_NPC(ch)
        &&  IS_SET(ch->plr_flags, PLR_GHOST))
            return TRUE;

        /* clan defenders can attack anyone in their clan */
        if (victim->in_room
        &&  (clan = victim->in_room->area->clan)
        &&  victim->clan != clan
        &&  ch->clan == clan)
            return FALSE;

        /* otherwise ghosts are safe */
        if (IS_SET(victim->plr_flags, PLR_GHOST))
            return TRUE;
    }
    else if (victim->extracted)
        return TRUE;

    if (victim->fighting == ch
    ||  ch == victim
    ||  IS_IMMORTAL(ch))
        return FALSE;

    /* handle ROOM_PEACE flags */
    if ((victim->in_room && IS_SET(victim->in_room->room_flags, ROOM_PEACE))
    ||  (ch->in_room && IS_SET(ch->in_room->room_flags, ROOM_PEACE)))
        return TRUE;

    /* link dead players whose adrenalin is not gushing are safe */
    if (!IS_NPC(victim) && !IS_PUMPED(victim) && victim->desc == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    return !in_PK(ch, victim);
}
```

I'm trying to compile (make) it using Visual C++ 6.0 NMake (the project is '98 year) and it throws this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   Version 6.00.8168.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1988-1998. All rights reserved.

        cl.exe /nologo /ML /W3 /G4e /O2g /D "WIN32" /YX /c -I . -I ..\msgdb -I .
\COMM -I .\COMPAT -I .\DB -I .\OLC -I .\COMPAT\regex-win32 /Fofight.obj fight.c
Command line warning D4002 : ignoring unknown option '/Og'
fight.c
fight.c(1446) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'is_safe_raw'
fight.c(1446) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
fight.c(1446) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
fight.c(1520) : warning C4013: 'is_safe_raw' undefined; assuming extern returnin
g int
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

If I get out "inline" modifier - it compiles well. But I can't understand why. Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: What happens if you put inline before bool instead of after it?

Comment: I tried to replace 'inline' in different positions - still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the static?  I'd try this: `inline bool is_safe_raw(...)`  Another possibility is that the problem is actually with whatever is above the function definition.

Comment: 'inline bool is_safe_raw(...)' doesn't work too :(

Comment: Also, where are you picking up your definitions or `CHAR_DATA` from?

Comment: Actually I don't know - it's not my project and there're to much code to understand it :(

Comment: @user I'm afraid finding out these things is the joyless task of the professional programmer.

Comment: @Neil Yep, I know, but this project is just the game which I would like to play instead have a sex with code :) So disappointed :)

Answer (score 3):

Your source file has `.c` extension, which means that by default it will be compiled as C language source file. The compiler you are using is implementing the C89/90 version of C language, which does not have such thing as `inline`. Hence the error.

If this is supposed to be C++ code (and your question is tagged [C++]), you have to either give your file `.cpp` extension or use a compiler switch that would force the compiler to treat the file as C++ code.

If this is supposed to be C code, then with this compiler your are restricted to C89/90, which has no `inline` at all. The compiler might support some alternative keyword for function inlining as an extension. Could be `_inline` or `__inline` or something like that.

Comment: The compiler option /TP can be used to force the files to be treated as C++.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inline is delacred first, and second inline is only declared in header file. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem is that this project (and this code) was built, but I'm not sure which compiler was used (it's some version of visual c++). So change the code is not actually acceptable way to solve the problem. I suggest that I need some options to make, but I don't no which one.

Comment: well I the same issues and Microsoft documentation informed me that inline identifier shall only be used in header files. Why do you even want this code to have inline identifier. Unless it has to be extra fast I see no point.

Comment: You have misunderstood the documentation - you can use inline in both header and .cpp files.

Comment: @user - Aren`t there six service packs to VC6? What if one of those fixed a parsing bug?

Comment: @Bo Persson I thought about this too, but I hope it's wrong, coz find the "right" version becomes to difficult in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone has done a #define of inline to something unhelpful? You could try examining the preprocessor output (`/E`, I think) to see exactly what the compiler is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of the other variants, such as "__inline"?